# Javascript/Greasemonkey match(), regex

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I need to grab data from this text from this page:
http://www.chess.com/home/game_archive?sortby=&show=echess&member=deckers1066

I cannot seem to get it working using.

```
var text = document.body;

var results = text.match(/id=[0-9]*>/g);
```

I need to grab all occurrences that look something like this

/echess/game?id=60942234

I'm interested more in the id number

Comment: I think `document.body.toString(); // "[object HTMLBodyElement]"` would be the first insight into what's going wrong, http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/444991 should be the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two problems with your code; one is the string you want to search is `document.body.innerHTML` and the other is the RegExp is looking for the end tag to the element, `>` without a quote before it. Try this

```
var results = document.body.innerHTML.match(/id=\d+/g);
```

Note I completely ommited the end tag because this RegExp is greedy and it means you don't have to worry about HTML parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use regular expressions for this. You should be using a proper DOM parser (there are many available for pretty much every language) and then selecting the IDs using that.

If you insist on using regex (which I would recommend against), Paul S's answer is the best.

Comment: If OP was asking for anything element specific (i.e. looking at `<a href="..`) I would have written an answer like this, but I read the question as "find all similar strings in random text data". If the OP makes an edit changing this I may recommend your answer.